# Reverse Integer Catch overflow C++

Tags: c++, c++11, integer-overflow

Hello I am trying a simple reverse integer operation in c++. Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

class RevInteger {

public:
    int reverse(int x) 
    {
        int result = 0;
        bool isNeg = x > 0 ? false : true;
        x = abs(x);

        while (x != 0) 
        {
            result = result * 10 + x % 10;
            x = x / 10;
        }

        if (isNeg) 
            result *= -1;

        if (result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
            return 0;
        else
            return (int)result;
    }
};
```

When I give it an input as 1534236469; I want it to return me 0, instead it returns me some junk values. What is wrong in my program.  Also, I am trying to use the climits lib for the purpose, is there a simpler way of doing the same?

Comment: I am afraid it is unclear what you are asking for. What did you mean by "_reverse_"? `0` is not the reverse of `1534236469`. so what do you want the relation between your Inputs and Outputs to be?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `result` is an `int`. It can never be larger than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @FirstStep ... for integer values for eg : 123  I should receive the reverse 321 or for -123 i should have -321. however , when there is such a long integer it should just throw a 0. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ .. I have used break points and checked my results step by step. It never checks the if condition for the result to be bigger than INT_MAX or INT_MIN

Comment: @ArunavaNag the compiler will remove those checks because it is impossible

Comment: @M.M changed result to long long ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `long long` in place of `int` for the result, and check for overflow at the end:

```
long long result = 0;
/* the rest of your code */
return (int)result; // Now the cast is necessary; in your code you could do without it
```

Another approach is to convert the `int` to string, reverse it, and then use the standard library to try converting it back, and catch the problems along the way ([demo](http://ideone.com/8g1wJT)):

```
int rev(int n) {
    auto s = to_string(n);
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    try {
        return stoi(s);
    } catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you must stay within integers, an approach would be to check intermediate result before multiplying it by ten, and also checking for overflow after the addition:

```
while (x != 0) {
    if (result > INT_MAX/10) {
        return 0;
    }
    result = result * 10 + x % 10;
    if (result < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    x = x / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight , converting the result to long long works. However in VS2015 it throws a warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'int', possible loss of data

Comment: @ArunavaNag The warning is OK after a check that the value is less than or equal to INT_MAX.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {
public:
    int reverse(int x) {
        int reversed = 0;

        while (x != 0) {
            if (reversed > INT_MAX / 10 || reversed < INT_MIN / 10) return 0;
            reversed = reversed * 10 + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
        }        
        return reversed;
    }
};
```

If reversed bigger than 8 digit INT_MAX (INT_MAX / 10), then if we add 1 digit to reversed, we will have an int overflow. And similar to INT_MIN.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: If reversed bigger than 8 digit INT_MAX (INT_MAX / 10), then if we add 1 digit to reversed, we will have an int overflow. And similar to INT_MIN.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @daskblinkenlight; changing the result as long long and type casting at the end solves the problem.

Working class:

```
class intReverse {

public:
int reverse(int x) {

    long long result = 0;  // only change here
    bool isNeg = x > 0 ? false : true;
    x = abs(x);
    while (x != 0) {
        result = result * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    if (isNeg) {
        result *= -1;
    }
    if (result > INT_MAX || result < INT_MIN)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (int) result;
    }

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int reverse(int x) {
        int pop = 0;
        int ans = 0;
        while(x) {
            // pop
            pop = x % 10;
            x /= 10;

            // check overflow
            if(ans > INT_MAX/10 || ans == INT_MAX/10 && pop > 7) return 0;
            if(ans < INT_MIN/10 || ans == INT_MIN/10 && pop < -8) return 0;

            // push
            ans = ans * 10 + pop;

        }
        return ans;
    }
```